# ubuntu 18.10 doesn't boot to gdm after update

Tags: boot, gnome, gdm, 18.10

I've just updated to 18.10 from 18.04 and immediately hit a snag.
My os doesn't boot anymore. It starts then comes to a moment when splash appears then it disappears and what I see is a message that [ok] Started Gnome Display manager. Sometimes it's something other but still no boot.
Funny enough that if I hot ALT + F2 during boot it seems to restart gdm or something because I see how splash blinks and gdm loads, I can enter password and everything seems to be working.
Well, my question is what could it be and how to fix it because it's quite annoying.

Specs are: AMD® Ryzen 5 1500x quad-core processor × 8 15,7 GiB GeForce GTX 1060 6GB/PCIe/SSE2

Comment: Did you check your /var/log/syslog for errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have a problem with an older computer, with an older GPU. Try this...

- boot to recovery mode
- choose root access

type:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /      # to remount the disk r/w

sudo pico /etc/gdm3/custom.conf # edit this file
```

change:

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

to:

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

Then reboot.

Comment: Should not be the case considering that the PC is quite new(not a cutting edge but abnyway). Specs are:
AMD® Ryzen 5 1500x quad-core processor × 8
15,7 GiB
GeForce GTX 1060 6GB/PCIe/SSE2

Comment: No, I was wrong you were right. It's wayland. Solved the problem by uncommenting the line you pointed me to. Thanks!

Comment: @s0nicYouth you can try my answer, it won't cost anything. You can also use `nomodeset` in the kernel boot line to eliminate a GeForce issue. Also know that AMD had some processor recalls for Linux problems. You may be one of them.